# Hide completely from anywhere on my site any product that has no category. : wooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

In my wooCommerce platform, I do not want to show products that do not have a category selected. I mean which products categories is empty that's products are not display in my site.
Is it any way to do that?

Comment: Hey @Md. Mehedi Hassan! Do you mean removing completely from anywhere on your site any product that has no category? Have you looked at using the `woocommerce_product_object_query` filter? Would that solve your problem? Happy to write a full answer with code if you want.

Comment: Hey @DiegoColantoni - you are right. I want to hide completely anywhere on my site any product that has no category. I will be grateful to you to write a full answer with code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to retrieve `products`, and if you want to exclude products which have no category assigned to from everywhere in your site, then you will need to address all of them.

*WP_Query*

You can hook into the `pre_get_posts` action and modify the `tax_query` arg in order to exclude products in the `uncategorized` product category (only when the query post type is `product`). I'm in fact assuming `uncategorized` being the `slug` of the default product category (you will need to amend it to your specific configuration). E.g.:

```
function remove_uncategorized_products( $query ) {
  if ( is_admin() ) {
    return;
  }
  if ( 'product' !== $query->get( 'post_type' ) ) {
    return;
  }
  $tax_query = (array) $query->get( 'tax_query' );
  $tax_query[] = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => array( 'uncategorized' ),
    'operator' => 'NOT IN',
  );
  $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'remove_uncategorized_products' );
```

*WC_Query*

Similar to WP_Query, you can hook into the `woocommerce_product_query` action to modify the query. E.g.:

```
function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {
  $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );
  $tax_query[] = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => array( 'uncategorized' ),
    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
  );
  $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );
```

*WC_Product_Query (used by wc_get_products)*

In this case, we can't change the query args to exclude certain product categories. We can instead loop through each product returned by the query and check its category. E.g.:

```
function filter_uncategorized_products_out( $results, $args ) {
  $products = array();
  foreach ( $results as $p ) {
    $is_uncategorized = false;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $p->get_id(), 'product_cat' );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
      if ( 'uncategorized' === $term->slug ) {
        $is_uncategorized = true;
      }
    }
    if ( ! $is_uncategorized ) {
      $products[] = $p;
    }
  }
  return $products;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_object_query', 'filter_uncategorized_products_out', 10, 2 );
```

Please note that there are other ways to retrieve products (for example using `$wpdb` directly). You might need to check all the pages of your site to see if you have covered them all.